# The efficient way of thinking towards the problem

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I'm a beginner in coding. This is the code I wrote for the program to find whether the given number is perfect or not.

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    // x constraints 2<=i<10^4
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan  = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int sum = 1;
        for(int i =2 ;i<=x/2;i++)
            if(x%i==0)
                sum+=i;
        if(sum==x)
            System.out.println("it's a perfect Number");
        else 
            System.out.println("not a perfect number");
        
    }
}
```

But the thing is it is not efficient maybe it is around o(n/2).
I came through from the website  GFG
where while comparing to my code there is a salient difference between that code to me.
i.e for loop

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) 
{ 
    if (n % i==0) 
    { 
        if(i * i != n) 
            sum = sum + i + n / i; 
        else
            sum = sum + i; 
    } 
}
```

My question is how to write the code like above. I mean from where we have to think (what is the key point to start) to write efficient codes.
Please give your valuable answer and suggestions towards writing efficient ones.

Comment: Creating a more efficient algorithm require ingenuity.

Comment: @jxh sir, then how to improve that?  I am not clever I agree but I made it somewhat efficient by making to run the loop from n to n/2 only.  So, sir can you explain more to write efficient ones.

Comment: You are asking a really broad question, there is no "formula" to write efficient code, you just need to have creativity and knowledge in some fields in computer science and mathematics, if you don't know how to analyze algorithms - you won't know how to make them better (Efficient-wise).

Comment: It is like trying to improve anything. You might ask a race car engineer how to make a winning race car.

Comment: Anyway, studying existing algorithms and learning algorithm theory should give you a foundation to build upon, so you can start there.

Comment: @RulerOfJustice So sir, dumb ones like me cant progress in it sir? I asked this really broad ones as this is a vast community I thought there maybe someone started like me and overcame this inefficient way of writing. sir What ever suggestion you make it would be to me, sir. Thank you.

Comment: @chandu_reddim You're not dumb.  At worst, inexperienced.  And writing efficient code is at least as much about about understanding the nature of the problem (or perhaps more) as it is about coding.   In the perfect number example, that would be number theory.

Comment: @RulerOfJustice To be frank sir, I analyzed the working of that loop but the thing is why I didn't get to there. I am from non-it backgrounds so I think it takes time to write like that sir.

Comment: So, generally, you need to have a very solid and fundamental understanding of what your current algorithm is doing. Then, look to see if within your algorithm if there is wasted computation. For example, re-computing something that has already been computed, or performing a iterative search when a look up table could have been used. Then, devise a way of avoiding the wasted computation. However, leveraging existing algorithms that are known to be efficient is a very basic approach to this kind of problem solving, so studying existing solutions is a great start.

Comment: You can only apply knowledge if the knowledge was within your grasp to being with. A solid understanding of the relationship between modulus, multiplication, and division could have helped with devising the scheme you found. Or, understanding that your original loop was re-computing a divisor that you could have found more directly from the smaller one already found might have helped. So, begin by acquiring knowledge, and practice recognizing when certain knowledge is applicable (which would be self-directing what is normally taught in a classroom).

Comment: @chandu_reddim it's important to remember that a computer can't be made to run faster, only to do less work. So, to write efficient code, you have to be able to identify where unnecessary work is done, and eliminate it. Sometimes that can be done by cutting stuff out; other times it requires you to come at the problem from a different angle. You learn approaches and tricks by practising, studying, and working with others. Everybody starts from the beginning: good luck on your journey.

Comment: @WJS Thank you sir your answer makes me not lower my self-esteem.

Comment: @jxh Thank you sir.

Comment: @WJS As I am not from English territory so I even didn't read your comment completely sir. It's ok sir.